# How to merge multiple cases into one in SPSS?

Tags: merge, spss

I want to fill in missing values for a case with values from cases in a different file. The corresponding cases have the same refrence number, variable REF. In the end, there should only be be one case per reference number, with no missing values in any variable. I already tried: Data-> Merge files-> Add variable-> many to one, but I still end up with multiple cases per reference number or no change at all in the table. I can't figure out how this works.

My two data sets:

```
REF p1 p2 p3
1   5  NA NA    
2   3  NA NA    
3   4  NA NA

REF p1  p2 p3
1   NA  3  NA   
1   NA  NA 1    
2   NA  2  NA
2   NA  NA 4
3   NA  1  NA   
3   NA  NA 1
```

Desired output:

```
REF p1 p2 p3
1   5  3  1 
2   3  2  4 
3   4  1  1
```

What I tried, but did not work:

[image: merge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first stack the two files, so that all the data is in one table, then use aggregation to get all the data for each case into one line. I suggest aggregation using the `max` function under the assumption that for every `REF` only one value exists in each column, so the aggregation will select this value and leave out the other "competing" missing values.

**EDITED** to leave only one line per "REF":

```
add files /file = dataset1 /file = dataset2.
exe.
dataset name gen.
aggregate /outfile=* /break=REF /P1 P2 P3=max(P1 P2 P3).
```

Comment: How could you get the desired output if all the cases are not in two different data sets, but in the same file?

Comment: If all the other parameters of the question apply, then you can just skip the `add files` and just use the `aggregate`