# 'Fill down' in SPSS

Tags: time-series, spss

I have a dataset where each person has an observation in two rows, but only half of the data is complete in each observation.

Something like this:

| ID | Var 1 | Var 2 | Var 3 | Var 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | . | . | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | . | . |
| 2 | . | . | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | . | . |

This is similar to [this task in Stata](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-fill-downexpand-observations-with-respect-to-a-time-variable/).

Is there a way to 'fill down (/up)' in SPSS, such that each filled variable in the two person observations gets combined into one complete variable per person?

I've tried looking through the available commands, but nothing seems to fulfill this task effectively.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045894/how-to-merge-multiple-cases-into-one-in-spss/70048177#70048177) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have to select a value or combine values, an aggregation will do the job very easily - like this:

```
aggregate /outfile=* /break=ID /Var1 to Var4=max(Var1 to Var4).
```

Comment: Worked great! Thank you for your help.

Just a note to future viewers that this command can be accessed graphically through 'Data > Aggregate'.